# Send multiple files via PHP curl to Spring Boot API

Tags: php, spring, curl, multipartfile

I want so send multiple uploaded files from my PHP application via curl to my Spring Boot API.

My API is defined like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public MyApiResponse createOrUpdate(@RequestPart("data") MyDataDto myDataDto,
    @RequestPart(value = "images", required = false) MultipartFile[] images) {
    ...
}
```

Which means that i can possibly upload multiple files.

I tried my API with Postman and it works fine.
[image]

So now i want to use this API in my PHP application with the following code:

### First approach

```
function uploadFiles($data, $fileInputName, $url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    
    $postFields = array();
    
    // Convert data to file
    $tempFile = tmpfile();
    fwrite($tempFile, json_encode($data));
    $tempFilePath = stream_get_meta_data($tempFile)['uri'];
    $postFields["data"] = curl_file_create($tempFilePath, "application/json");
    
    // Pack image for sending
    $countFiles = count($_FILES[$fileInputName]["size"]);
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countFiles; $i++) {
        if ($_FILES[$fileInputName]['size'][$i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        $postFields["images[".$j++."]"] = curl_file_create(
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['tmp_name'][$i],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['type'][$i],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['name'][$i]
        );
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    unset($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

With this solution zero images are received in my API.

### Second approach

I also tried collecting my curl_files in another array

```
        $images[] = curl_file_create(
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['tmp_name'][$i],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['type'][$i],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['name'][$i]
        );
```

and set it as `$postFields["images"] = $images` but this didn't work either.

### Third approach

The only thing that worked so far was to set one single file to the key "images"

```
        $postFields["images"] = curl_file_create(
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['tmp_name'][0],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['type'][0],
            $_FILES[$fileInputName]['name'][0]
        );
```

But i clearly want to send *multiple Files*. :(

**So how can i manage to send multiple curl_files with the same key "images"?**

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, if you don't want to create the request body in string format yourself. The "syntax" of using square brackets in the parameter name is what the manual for `CURLFile::__construct` suggests to upload multiple files. PHP itself would _need_ this, if it was the _receiver_ of this request - otherwise, it would simply overwrite parameters with the same name. [...]

Comment: [...] But if the receiving end in this case, your Spring Boot API, it not able to handle square brackets in the parameter name (but instead expects multiple parameters named just `images`), then I don't see any direct way to solve this - you can't pass multiple array entries under the same key for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: Does it have to be cURL, or can you use a different HTTP request client, like Guzzle? The format that one uses to pass parameters for a multipart request, should allow you to use the parameter name `images`, without square brackets, multiple times - https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-form-files

Comment: Thanks for that hint, @CBroe! I'm looking into Guzzle then, it looks promising :)